# Split a file based on a particular search pattern and also have a particular number of lines in the split file using AWK command

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, split

I have a requirement where I have to split a file at an underscore pattern and the lines in the resulting file should have a maximum of 5 lines, if the result exceeds 5 lines the file name should be changed and the rest of the lines should be put in the other split files and then the result should be grouped.

**For eg:**

My file contains,

```
ADD1_5001AB
ADD1_5002AB
ADD1_5003BC
ADD1_5004AB
ADD1_5005AB
ADD1_5006BC
ADD1_5007AB
ADD1_5008AB
ADD1_5009BC
ADD1_5010AB
ADD1_5011AB
ADD1_5012BC
ADD2_5100XY
ADD2_5101YZ
CANC1_5200AB
CANC1_5201BC
CANC2_5301GH 
CANC2_5302FG
```

So my result should have 6 files,

**1st file should contain,**

```
ADD1_5001AB
ADD1_5002AB 
ADD1_5003BC 
ADD1_5004AB
ADD1_5005AB
```

**2nd file should contain,**

```
ADD1_5006BC
ADD1_5007AB
ADD1_5008AB
ADD1_5009BC
ADD1_5010AB
```

**3rd file should contain,**

```
ADD1_5011AB
ADD1_5012BC
```

**4th file should contain,**

```
ADD2_5100XY
ADD2_5101YZ
```

**5th file should contain,**

```
CANC1_5200AB
CANC1_5201BC
```

**6th file should contain,**

```
CANC2_5301GH
CANC2_5302FG
```

Kindly Help.

Comment: Now, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried awk -F"_" '{print $0 > $1}'. But unable to split based on line number

Comment: I'm fairly new to shell scripting.

Comment: For splitting use `split`. try `split --help` to get its usage

Comment: Can you please help me how I can use both awk and split together, as the file has to be split at the underscore and also the new split file should not contain more than 5 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
awk -F _ 'prefix != $1 || line == 5 { line = 0; ++slab; out = sprintf("out%02d.txt", slab); prefix = $1 } { ++line; print > out }' input.txt
```

Where `input.txt` is the input file. This works as follows: `_` is used as a field separator, so `$1` is the prefix before the first `_`. Then:

```
# prefix contains the last seen first field. When it changes or when the last
# slab grew to five lines long, we need to start a new output file. So
prefix != $1 || line == 5 {
  line = 0                            # reset line counter
  ++slab                              # increase slab number
  out = sprintf("out%02d.txt", slab)  # use that number to generate a new output
                                      # file name
  prefix = $1                         # and remember the new prefix
}

# then, for all lines:
{
  ++line                              # increase line counter
  print > out                         # and print the line to the current output
                                      # file.
}
```

As given, this will generate files `out01.txt`, `out02.txt` and so forth. Change the format string in the `sprintf` call to customize that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working as I wanted. Warm regards.